# Acronym OP for a new user

Tags: discussion

I came across a question asked by a new user. The new user was refered to as OP in the comment section. I'm not familiar with what it means in that context. Can someone clarify this for me? Is there a particular background story to that acronym?

Comment: Yeah I remember I was confused about this too when I first came on this website. Then I saw more comments saying, "referring to the OP", and then I was like, "OH! It must mean, 'original post'... and then if people describe it as a person, it's 'original poster'..." LOL :)

Comment: Op  is short for Operational as  in Op Amp so we can guess by context if it a personal or impersonal noun.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It stands for "Original Poster" — the person who wrote the post (question or answer) being discussed.

Answer (score 3):

It can mean Original Post, or Original Poster, and often used interchangeably both here and on the web in general. It's very old internet slang/shorthand that pre-dates Stack Exchange/Stack Overflow. See ["Does OP mean “original poster” or “original post”?"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/424366/does-op-mean-original-poster-or-original-post) on the English stack exchange for more info and examples.

Comment: OP in other context (gaming) can also mean "Over Powered".

Comment: I was only aware of that meaning @R.Joshi

Comment: @R.Joshi or Operator :)